# Pandas groupby column values from a list and filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
id variable year
1     a     2020
1     a     2030
1     a     2040
1     a     2050
1     b     2020
1     b     2030
1     b     2040
1     b     2050
1     c     2020
1     c     2030
1     c     2040
1     c     2050
```

Now for variables in a list `var = ['a','b']`, I want to only keep 2020 and 2030 rows. While for the rest of the variables (ie, `c` in above example), I want to keep 2020, 2030, and 2040 rows. Therefore final dataframe should be:

```
id variable year
1     a     2020
1     a     2030
1     b     2020
1     b     2030
1     c     2020
1     c     2030
1     c     2040
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with chain by `|` for bitwise `OR`, `&` for bitwise `AND` and also `~` for invert mask:

```
var =  ['a','b']
var1 = [2020,2030]
var2 = [2020,2030,2040]

m1 = df['variable'].isin(var)
m2 = df['year'].isin(var1)
m3 = df['year'].isin(var2)

df = df[(m1 & m2) | (~m1 & m3)]
print (df)
    id variable  year
0    1        a  2020
1    1        a  2030
4    1        b  2020
5    1        b  2030
8    1        c  2020
9    1        c  2030
10   1        c  2040
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the excellent solution provided would be to use the [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#the-query-method) method:

```
search_criteria = "variable in ('a','b') and year in (2020, 2030) or variable=='c' and year in (2020, 2030, 2040)"
df.query(search_criteria)   

    id  variable    year
0   1      a       2020
1   1      a       2030
4   1      b       2020
5   1      b       2030
8   1      c       2020
9   1      c       2030
10  1      c       2040
```